# Using a PI zero as a USB stick & customize(spoof) the PID & VID & s/n

Tags: usb

Is it possible to use a Pi zero as a USB stick while spoofing a VID & PID & sn through a service or a custom driver?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For USB stick and USB VID/PID see [this paper](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_configfs.txt) related to linux gadget. (recent raspbian is require for libcomposite kernel module)

```
Each gadget needs to have its vendor id <VID> and product id <PID> specified::

    $ echo <VID> > idVendor
    $ echo <PID> > idProduct

A gadget also needs its serial number, manufacturer and product strings.
In order to have a place to store them, a strings subdirectory must be created
for each language, e.g.::

    $ mkdir strings/0x409

Then the strings can be specified::

    $ echo <serial number> > strings/0x409/serialnumber
    $ echo <manufacturer> > strings/0x409/manufacturer
    $ echo <product> > strings/0x409/product
```

You can also check [isticktoit.net](https://www.isticktoit.net/?p=1383) for libcomposite examples : **Serial Adapter**, **Ethernet Adapter**, **Keyboard / Mouse / Joystick (HID)** and for you probably **Mass storage** example.